# webjure vs compojure?

Tags: clojure, compojure

I've heard of two Clojure based web application frameworks: Webjure and Compojure. Can someone let me know which is better?

Comment: These names are getting silly now.

Comment: @Dan: I'm waiting for Abjure, if it doesn't already exist!

Answer (score 4):

Now you can add [Ring](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/bbc9fd453667d953#) to the list.  All of these frameworks are very new and likely to evolve (or die) quickly, but Compojure does seem to be the most actively developed based on the past 6 months or so.

"Better" is too subjective a question to get a definitive answer to.  Try them all and see what works.

Comment: Ring is not a competitor to Compojure; Compojure is built on top of Ring.

Answer (score 4):

Compojure has been working very well for me so far. I like the simplicity of the design, the flexibility and the fact that it encourages a nice idiomatic functional style.

Sample server:

```
(use 'compojure)

(defroutes my-app
  (GET "/index.html"
    (html 
      [:h1 "Hello World!!"]
      [:body "This is some text"]))
  (ANY "*"
    [404 "Page not found"]))

(run-server {:port 80}
  "/*" (servlet my-app))
```

Note that Compojure uses Ring internally.

Answer (score 3):

I second Rayne's recommendation on Moustache.

Right now, we are using Ring (base layer, middleware), Moustache (routing), Hiccup (html generation).  We just began using Compass for CSS (http://compass-style.org/). So far, I'm happy with this collection of small libraries rather than a big "complete stack" framework (Django, Rails, ect...).

Answer (score 3):

Now, there is also a new one named [Noir](http://www.webnoir.org/) build on top of compojure. Really recommended, especially with [Heroku](http://thecomputersarewinning.com/post/clojure-heroku-noir-mongo).

Answer (score 2):

Compojure seems to be getting the most buzz right now.  Not necessarily indicative of quality, but the one with the most eyes will probably evolve the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Moustache](http://github.com/cgrand/moustache), which is what I use in [TryClojure](http://tryclj.licenser.net), along with Ring. It's pretty awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Compojure is based on Ring, which is a low-level framework that doesn't attempt to hide much of HTTP. It's similar to WSGI (Python) or Rack (Ruby). Ring has a concept of middleware, small pieces of code that can do something meaningful with an HTTP request and/or response, such as dump header infos, manage cookies etc. Compojure is a higher-level framework, somewhat similar to Ruby's Sinatra. Its aim is to provide a convenient API (or DSL, if you prefer) for most tasks a Web app developer faces. It's usually used together with an HTML generation library, such as Hiccup.

I haven't heard much about Webjure in the last few months, I'm not sure it's in active development (but I'd be interested to find out more). It precedes Ring, AFAICT, which seems to have become somewhat of a standard for Clojure Web frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

I've been building a project for my own use using Compojure and it has worked out great. It doesn't really get in the way very much and lets you focus on what's important, your problem domain. The project is about 1100 lines of clojure just to give you an idea of the size.